# tinymce adobe air

Tags: adobe, air, tinymce

Is it possible to get tinymce working inside Adobe air? I found [this tut](http://www.whypad.com/posts/adobe-air-using-a-rich-text-editor-tinymce-tutorial/139/) but it is out of date and no longer works with current versions.

Normal tinymce produces these errors:

```
1. TypeError: Result of expression 'g.base_uri' [undefined] is not an object.
2. TypeError: Result of expression 'tinyMCE.init' [undefined] is not a function.
```

Jquery tinymce produces the error:

```
Can't find variable: tinymce
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This thread of the tinymce forum](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=12681) might help you further or at least give you some more information.

Comment: thanks for the link. [Spocke said he got it working](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?pid=42286#p42286) in 2008 but there is no code examples and later comments show that devs cannot get it working with the current versions. I am not getting any of the security problems though, just 'undefined' errors.

Comment: then i suggest you ask in the tinymce forum directly, if you are lucky one of the geeks there can provide you with the right answers